# Numpy fromfile reading after EOF

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

All,

have some float values stored in a binary file and am reading them back. Windows 10, x64, Anaconda 5.1, Python 3.6, Numpy 0.14.1. File is open with 'rb' flag. Reading with 'np.fromfile' works fine except when I tried to read beyond the file. I have piece of code which checks if file is at EOF

```
    try:
        _ = struct.unpack('f', f.read(4))[0]
        # if successfull, means we did something wrong, should be an exception thrown
        raise RuntimeError("There is something wrong with KDD file,  it's TOO LONG!")
    except struct.error as ex:
        # got and exception, file is ok, return good values
        pass
```

which basically check that I read everything from file. Works very well. Today I played with it and thought that I could remove dependency on `struct` and just replace line `_ = struct.unpack('f', f.read(4))[0]` with `_ = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32, count=1, sep="")` , supposed to get different exception and handle it in the same way, ...

But! No exception was raised, none, and I got my own RuntimeError. Is it a bug? How in general I suppose to know if I read beyond EOF?

Comment: Repeated `fromfile` from the same open file returns a `(0,)` shape array, which displays as `array([], dtype=float64)`.

Comment: @hpaulj ah, good to know. Is it stated as a policy for all numpy I/O? Load/Save works in the same way as well?

Comment: Try it yourself.  `np.save` doesn't just save raw data bytes.  It writes an initial block with shape and dtype information.  So if the `load` fails to find that, it tries to use `pickle`, and if that fails it raises an error.

Comment: @hpaulj if this is not stated as a policy, trying is a bit useless - it might work for this particular version but fail for next one. There is also numpy memmap - who knows what it is doing?

Comment: Python stated policy: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read: `An empty string is returned when EOF is encountered immediately`